# Rails 3 optional scope url generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, routes

I have the following defined in my routes.rb

```
scope '(:subdomain)' do
  resource :highscore
end
```

now I can reach the same resource on these paths

```
/highscore
/test/highscore
```

however, when I generate a url using

```
highscore_path
```

it will always generate the /highscore path, however, i'd like it to generate a /test/highscore path when inside the test subdomain

i tried manipulating default_url_options or

```
highscore_path(:subdomain => 'test')
```

but it always omits the test. How do I work around this, preferrably without having to change all of my urls?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the specifier 'subdomain' was silly :( replace that with anything else and it'll work!

I've overwritten default_url_options in the application_controller with

```
def default_url_options
  return {:identifier => 'test'}.merge(super)
end
```

Comment: You should accept your answer, or are you waiting for more?